# JMeter Thread Group Not Looping After While Loop with URL list from CSV Data Set

Tags: jmeter

I have a list of URLs that I am pulling from a CSV data set with the variable defined as url and using each ${url} as a counter for a while loop. The condition in the while loop is only ${url}. I have the following options set in the CSV Data Set:

Recycle on EOF: False
Stop thread on EOF: True

I have a HTTP request sampler under the while controller, which is working as expected, my list of 20 URLs will be requested successfully, and if I add another thread, it will request the same URLs in parallel no problem.

However, setting the loop iteration in the Thread Group to 2, or having a loop controller as a parent of the while loop set to 2 will not have the user request the list of URLs again.

I am hoping to understand the logic here, my goal would be to able to set the # of times/loops I want the full list of URLs to be requested and also understand how to set a delay between each time the same (or different user/thread) will request the URL. I know there are Constant Timers that can be added to the Loop Controller....but as of right now it doesn't control the number of times the while controller will run. I'm sure it has to do with "Stop thread on EOF", but I need to do that so EOF isn't set as all future URL requests, which is what I see and what the [Apache docs say](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config:%7E:text=If%20the%20recycle%20option%20is%20false%2C%20and%20stopThread%20is%20false%2C%20then%20all%20the%20variables%20are%20set%20to%20%3CEOF%3E%20when%20the%20end%20of%20file%20is%20reached.%20This%20value%20can%20be%20changed%20by%20setting%20the%20JMeter%20property%20csvdataset.eofstring.)

"If the recycle option is false, and stopThread is false, then all the variables are set to  when the end of file is reached. This value can be changed by setting the JMeter property csvdataset.eofstring."

I guess I don't understand why "Stop thread on EOF" will prevent even the thread group loop iteration from running again. I assumed a new loop iteration = new thread is created, but I guess it considers it the same thread, and with that thread being 1, it stops entirely.

[Screenshot of my thread group in the JMeter GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9lqx.png)

*EDIT*

I was able to get the behavior I expected with the following, although I am not sure what is more performant for load testing. I want to make sure each URL is getting requested every x seconds, where x is 1 to 5 seconds(depending on the throughput I can get).

If this is the best way to do what I am hoping, what would be the best for performance?

1. Used loop controller instead of a while controller.
2. Used 20 threads which will request each of the 20 URLs in a sequential manner from the list in the CSV file
3. CSV data set has recycle on EOF: True and stop thread on EOF: False Sharing Mode: All Threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `Stop thread on EOF: True` it means that when the last entry is read the thread (virtual user) is being shut down, no more iterations will be made or no further requests will be executed.

If you want  to run all the requests from the CSV file and then continue you can take a look at **Reading all Values from the CSV and Continue** chapter of the [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter#Use) article.

If you need to start reading the CSV file again once it reached the end you need to set `Recycle on EOF: True` and `Stop thread on EOF: False` or switch to [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead)